# Integrate Shopify with Elgg

Tags: integration, shopify, elgg

We are seeking to integrate a Shopify store with Elgg (PHP-based, open source, social networking framework). Our Elgg site will be membership-based. Elgg members will pass to the Shopify store for purchases, and we need to be able to associate Elgg Member IDs with Orders on the Shopify store.

A couple of related questions...

1. can you pass in an ID (from our Elgg site) to the Shopify store and get it associated with the Shopify Order data?
2. On Shopify order completion, can you specify a redirect URL?
3. On shopify order completion, can you specify a URL for Restful/Ajax event notifiction?

Comment: Not sure about the first two, but for number 3 you can definitely use the [_orders/create_ webhook](http://api.shopify.com/webhook.html#create).

Answer (score 1):

1. No, but you can do the opposite. You can use Shopify's authentication system to log someone in to Elgg.
2. No.
3. No, but there are webhooks for event notification.